# Which set did this head with horns come from?

Tags: set-identification, ninjago

Bought in a lot sale and can't seem to find which set this is from, looks to be a partial dragon or snake? The lot had some Nexo knights and Ninjago stuff.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

It seems to be a slightly modified sub-assembly from [Ninjago Dragon Pit (70655)](https://brickset.com/sets/70655-1/Dragon-Pit)

[image]

Comment: You are amazing Alex, thank you!